# Can a creature with Ninjutsu attack a different target as the creature it replaces?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Consider the following situation:

1. It is player A's turn.
2. Player A has 3 1/1 creatures.
3. Player B has 1 1/1 blocker and a planeswalker at 2 loyalty.
4. Player A has all of their creatures attack the planeswalker.
5. Player B can't save their planeswalker, so they don't take the trade, leaving all three creatures unblocked.
6. Player A ninjutsu's a ninja from their hand, replacing one of the unblocked attackers.

Can the ninja attack player B's face, or must it attack the same planeswalker as the original creature?

Relatedly, in a commander game, can an unblocked attacker against Player B be ninjutsu'd to create an unblocked attacker against Player C?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No, the creature with Ninjutsu is attacking the same thing as the creature it replaced.**

In the [Ninjutsu rules](https://mtg.fandom.com/wiki/Ninjutsu), rule 702.49c says

> A ninjutsu ability may be activated only while a creature on the battlefield is unblocked (see rule 509.1h). The creature with ninjutsu is put onto the battlefield unblocked. **It will be attacking the same player, planeswalker, or battle as the creature that was returned to its owner’s hand.**